# Quotient of two smooth functions with same vanishing locus is $C^1$

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be smooth functions on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, $n > 1$, and suppose that $dg \neq 0$. Say that $f$ vanishes on the vanishing locus of $g$. It is claimed that $f/g$ is $C^1$, but I can't quite show why this is the case.  When you differentiate you get
$$ df/g - (f/g^2) dg $$
and while in all the examples I have done there is cancellation, I can't see why this has to hold in general.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider locally choosing coordinates $y_1,\dots,y_{2n}$ with $y_1 = g$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that since $dg\neq 0$ on the vanishing locus of $g$, $g$ vanishes linearly on it. But $f$ can only vanish at those points either in a linear way or higher. In the first case, $f$ is locally proportional to $g$ ang $f/g$ is finite and well behaved there. In the second, $f/g$ vanishes but is still well behaved.  In a sentence: $g$ is an infinitesimal of the lowest possible order there.